# Win32 Bitmap won't load

Tags: c, winapi, win32gui

I've got this code to load a bitmap:

```
HBITMAP reg_hbmCS = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hRegWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        reg_hbmCS = LoadBitmap(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_CSBITMAP));
        if(!reg_hbmCS)
            MessageBox(hRegWnd,
                "No se ha podido cargar el icono del programa.\r\n"
                "Pruebe a reinstalar el programa para solucionar este problema.",
                "Atención", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DeleteObject(reg_hbmCS);
        DestroyWindow(hRegWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hRegWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the reg_hbmCS won't load, so I don't have the bitmap available (it prompts with the message box in `(if !reg_hbmCS)`.

Here my resources.h:

```
#ifndef RESOURCES_H
#define RESOURCES_H

#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC      -1
#endif

#define IDI_CSICO       101

#define IDB_CSBITMAP    201

#endif // RESOURCES_H
```

And my resources.rc:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resources.h"

IDI_CSICO ICON "CS-Nursing.ico"

IDB_CSBITMAP BITMAP DISCARDABLE "CS-Nursing.bmp"
```

In case it was necessary, I use Code::Blocks 12.11 on WindowsXP SP3.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this in a DLL or an EXE?  DLLs need to cache the HINSTANCE on dll load so that calls to LoadBitmap (et.al.) go to the DLL's resources, not the calling EXE's.

Comment: Did you verify with a resource viewer/editor that your bitmap is, in fact, being compiled into your executable?

Comment: Also make sure that your bitmap is valid. A lot of tools produce bitmaps with invalid bitmap headers. Open the bitmap in MS Paint and save it again.

Comment: It is an EXE, it is being compiled:

windres.exe  -J rc -O coff -i C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\MYDOCU~1\CS-NUR~1\RESOUR~1.RC -o obj\Debug\resources.res
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\CS-Nursing.exe obj\Debug\main.o  obj\Debug\resources.res   -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lcomctl32 
Output size is 758.79 KB

And I will have to check te validity of the bitmap.

Comment: Opened the bitmap with MS Paint, saved it again, still not loading.

Comment: You can try to edit your rc with http://www.resedit.net/ to see if it open and show your bitmap well.

Comment: The way to indicate that your problem is solved is to accept an answer (click the check mark). Please don't edit "[SOLVED]" into the title.

Answer (score 1):

LoadBitmap is probably failing because you haven't told it where to find the bitmap resource. The first parameter to LoadBitmap is a handle to the instance of the module containing the bitmap resource (unless you are loading a system bitmap in which case it is NULL). Since the bitmap resource is being compiled into your application, you need to pass a handle to the instance of your application module as the first parameter when you call LoadBitmap. You can get this handle from the first parameter in your WinMain function. Many people store this parameter in a global variable so that it can be accessed easily from other functions. If the call to LoadBitmap still fails then you should call GetLastError to get a code describing why the call failed. See [Windows System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Added "HINSTANCE hRegisInstance;" as a global and "hRegisInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hRegWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE); // "reg_hbmCS = LoadBitmap(hRegisInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_CSBITMAP));" but still doesn't load it, I'll look for the GetLastError

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have added a function for the GetLastError() and I get "No error message has been recorded", which would mean an error message of "0", every moment from the start of the program to the end of it.

Comment: You should call GetWindowLongPtr instead of GetWindowLong because on 64bit versions of Windows the GWL_HINSTANCE could be bigger than a long. When GetLastError returns zero it does not mean that no error has occurred since the start of the program, it means that the last Windows API function that set the error code set it to zero. So when you need to call GetLastError to learn why a function call failed you must make sure you don't call any Windows API functions before you call GetLastError (at least not any that set the error code).

Answer (score 0):

Changed the resources.rc file:

```
//IDB_CSBITMAP BITMAP DISCARDABLE "CS-Nursing.bmp"
IDB_CSBITMAP BITMAP "CS-Nursing.bmp"
```

Now it works perfectly, will mark this as solved, thank you all for your help.